# In Angular 7, why HttpClient.post is getting executed twice even if subscribed only once?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular7, angular-httpclient

Only once I am subscribed to this observable from HttpClient.post. However, post request is getting executed twice, and thus adding same record twice. Note that all debug log statement shows, that only successful response from subscribe function is being printed (and executed) twice.

```
  addTemplate(template) {
      console.log('In addTemplate');
      let authHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
      authHeaders = authHeaders.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('id_token'));
      authHeaders = authHeaders.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      const httpOptions = {
        headers: authHeaders,
        observe: 'body' as 'body',
        responseType: 'json' as 'json'
      };
      console.log('^^^^^ addTemplate  Service Header  = ', httpOptions);

      this.httpClient.post<any>(this.constants.URL + 'addTemplate', JSON.stringify(template),
        {headers: authHeaders}).pipe().subscribe(
        (response) => {  console.log ('Added Template Successfully -->', response)},
        (error) => { console.error('Got an Error while adding Template ->', error) }
      );
   }
```

Above function is called from here:

```
 saveTemplate(){
      const saveTemplate : ITemplate = Object.assign({}, this.templateForm.value);
      console.log('Adding new Template with name -->', saveTemplate.name);
      this.templateService.addTemplate(saveTemplate);
  }
```

Here's the image of browser console:

[image]

Here's the image of browser's Network tab:

[image]

As you can see HttpClient.post call to addTemplate REST API is being called twice. Even if post call is subscribed only once and there is no other place it's being called from. Call log

```
  console.log('^^^^^ addTemplate  Service Header  = ', httpOptions);
```

in addTemplate function in service is executed once but log (response) => {  console.log ('Added Template Successfully -->', response)},  is executed twice.

I did try changing call to httpClient.post to use share()  and publishLast().refCount() but nothing worked. Maybe I didn't do it right.

Using Angular 7.2 with rxjs 6.5.2 and rxjs/compat (Yes, I do have some legacy code that needs to upgrade to latest)

Comment: Are you sure that both requests are the same? Maybe the first one is of type OPTIONS

Comment: Yes both are same requests. That's why same record is being added twice in the backend (through REST API)

Comment: who's firing that `saveTemplate()` method? a click event?

Comment: This is fired only once. As you can see "^^^^^ addTemplate  Service Header  =" message within addTemplate service function is printed only once while 'Added Template Successfully' is printed twice.

Comment: ).pipe().subscribe( remove the `pipe()` that is not needed and try one more time

Comment: Yes I did try that too. Still the same problem.

Comment: Are you using any HTTP interceptors?

Comment: Any http interceptors? are you using the same versions for both rxjs and rxjs/compat?

Comment: @Reactgular & Jota.Toledo, Not using HTTP interceptors. Yes, both versions of rxjs and rxjs-compat are same. 

Also, to note that this application was upgraded from Angular 4 to 7 and other parts of application may still be using HttpModule instead of HttpClientModule. Would that cause such behavior?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your source code. I would recommend starting a new Angular project and copying the affected components and services to this project as isolation and see if you can still reproduce.

Comment: Please show exactly how saveTemplate() is being called from the template/view. How the form is structured and submitted could cause duplicate submissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake. The form was calling saveTemplate() as well as button... So it was being called twice.

```
<form [formGroup]="templateForm" autocomplete="off" novalidate (ngSubmit)="saveTemplate()">
```

Button:

```
          <button mat-button mat-raised-button color="primary"
              type="submit" (click)="saveTemplate()" [disabled]="templateForm.pristine">Save
```

Thanks @CaptainFindus, @Alexander Staroselsky and all for your help